# issues with removing whitespace after the output file is created in perl

Tags: perl

I have written a script that saves the output in a Perl script, but for some reason it is leaving the space at the end of each line. I tried using Perl regex but it does not work. Can someone please look at my code and let me know what I am doing wrong?

MY CODE

```
 open FILE, ">", "finaloutput.txt" || die "cannot create";
 my @output = ``; # (here i am using back ticks to run third party command)
 foreach  my $output (@output) {
     chomp $output;
     my $remove_whitespace = $output;
     $remove_whitespace =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
     print  FILE "$remove_whitespace  \n";
 }
 close FILE;
```

Even after doing this it is leaving a white space at the end of each line in output. Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: when you do `print  FILE "$remove_whitespace  \n";` you add 2 spaces at the end of each line, do print  FILE "$remove_whitespace\n";` instead

Comment: @mirod make that an answer, so we can upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting two spaces at the end of every line:

```
print  FILE "$remove_whitespace  \n";
                               ^^
                               ||
```

Get rid of those! Solutions:

```
print FILE "$remove_whitespace\n";
  -or-
print FILE $remove_whitespace, "\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

when you do `print FILE "$remove_whitespace \n";` you add 2 spaces at the end of each line, do `print FILE "$remove_whitespace\n";` instead

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you're including multiple spaces at the end of your `print` statement. Change your print statement to:

```
print FILE "$remove_whitespace\n";
```

Also, you shouldn't be using global-style file handles any more. Instead, use something like:

```
open my $file, '>', "output.txt";
print $file "Some string\n";
close $file;
```